# Sampling a matrix of an AR model

Tags: dynamical-systems, random-matrices

Let us consider a dynamic system $x_t = A x_{t-1}+v_t$ where $v_t$ is multivariate normal noise with zero mean, i.e. $v_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ and $A$ is a matrix. As far as I know, for some $A$, the system is not stable, namely when there is an eigenvalue larger than zero.

My question: how to sample a random matrix $A$ so the system is stable.

Comment: I would expect this to be unstable iff there is a singular value $\ge 1$.  Do you want a probability distribution on $n \times n$ matrices whose singular values are less than $1$?

Comment: Yes, actually, that is what I wish.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Feel free to modify the question so it make sense to you - I am not an expert in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to generate "random" $n \times n$ matrices with all singular values $< 1$.  Write $A = U \Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V^T$ are orthogonal matrices and
$\Sigma$ is diagonal.  For the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$, take a sample of
size $n$ from the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.  To generate random orthogonal matrices, you could use e.g. [these methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Randomization).